# Essential singularity of an entire function at infinity

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $ and  $g: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $ be meromorphic function and given that $ \frac{f(z)}{g(z)}$ is an entire function. Is it true that if $f,g$ have no essential singularity at $z=\infty$ then $\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}$ has no essential singularity at $z=\infty$. I think this is true . But unable to proof.

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ have not an essential singularity then they have a removable singularity or a pole at $z = \infty$. What does that tell you about $f/g$?

Comment: then $\frac{f}{g}$ is also meromorphic .

Comment: Because $ f/g$ will also has either pole or removable singularity at $\infty$.